# Questions regarding the goal of finance and agency

Tags: accounting

I found this question in a past year paper for a finance module

The goal of finance is to maximise shareholders’ wealth.
A company is already meeting the government standards of safety and health at the work place. Suppose the company spends money to upgrade the cafeteria as well as provide some recreational facilities for its workers. Discuss whether this means that the management of the company is not maximising shareholder wealth.

My answer targeted that:
Since the safety and health standards had been met, the upgrades to cafeteria and recreational facilities are extra and do not maximise shareholders' wealth since these are extra costs. However the upgrades could provide more benefits like lower turnover rates and sick leaves which can boost productivity rate, leading to higher profits.

Is there anything I missed out? Or anything that could improve my answers.

Comment: How is your question related to personal finance?

Comment: There's not a definitive answer. You've given one reason for and against the assertion - there could be dozens of other possible effects, so I've voted to close as opinion-based.

Comment: Hi, I believe the question wants to find out on our understanding of whether this action by the management translates to nonalignment of interest with the shareholders

Comment: It's not a bad question, just not on-topic for this site (a Q&A site not a discussion board)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another factor is that every company is competing with others for employees. If you offer a better benefits package than your competitors, then you will be able to attract the best employees, as well as retaining the ones you already have.